# Week number of year becomes 1 during the last week of the year

Tags: swiftui

In this case, the output becomes 1 instead of 53 for the last week of the year, how can this be changed to show the proper week numbers?

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @State var date = Date()
    
    var weekFormatter: DateFormatter{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "w"
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date, label: {Text("Bing")})
            Text("\(date, formatter: weekFormatter)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the `w` character in the date format is described by [Unicode Technical Standard #35 Part 4 §8.4](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Patterns_Week_Of_Year). As of version 37, it says this:

> #### 8.4 Week of Year
>
> Values calculated for the Week of Year field range from 1 to 53 for the Gregorian calendar (they may have different ranges for other calendars). Week 1 for a year is the first week that contains at least the specified minimum number of days from that year. Weeks between week 1 of one year and week 1 of the following year are numbered sequentially from 2 to 52 or 53 (if needed). For example, January 1, 1998 was a Thursday. If the first day of the week is MONDAY and the minimum days in a week is 4 (these are the values reflecting ISO 8601 and many national standards), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998. However, if the first day of the week is SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on January 10, 1998. The first three days of 1998 are then part of week 53 of 1997.
>
> Values are similarly calculated for the Week of Month.

So, if you want to change the way the weeks are numbered, you need to change the first day of the week, or the minimum days in a week, or both. You do that by creating a [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar#), setting the `firstWeekday` and `minimumDaysInFirstWeek` properties, and then assigning the `Calendar` to your `DateFormatter`'s `calendar` property:

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.firstWeekday = ...
calendar.minimumDaysInFirstWeek = ...
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = calendar
formatter.dateFormat = "w"
```